# Should I store data in my custom UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have 2 viewControllers that each contains one UITableView among other subviews. The 2 UITableViews have the same section structure and cell types, but the data source is different.

So I decided to extract this UITableView into a custom UITableView. The custom UITableView implements methods like `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, and is its own data source and delegate. The viewController only provides data.

The question is I can't figure out which is the best way for viewControllers to provide data. I can think of 2 ways:

#### first way

in MyCustomTableView.h:

```
@protocol MyCustomTableViewDataProvider <NSObject>
- (NSArray*)dataArray;
@end

@interface MyCustomTableView : UITableView
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyCustomTableViewDataProvider> dataProvider;
@end
```

The viewController should implement this protocol:

```
- (NSArray*)dataArray {
    return self.dataArray;
}
```

And in MyCustomTableView.m I use it like:

```
NSArray* dataArray = [self.dataProvider dataArray];
```

#### second way

in MyCustomTableView.h:

```
@interface MyCustomTableView : UITableView
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSArray* dataArray;
@end
```

Every time when there's a change in data, the viewController should inform the custom TableView to update its data:

```
self.customTableView.dataArray = self.dataArray;
```

And in MyCustomTableView.m I use it like:

```
self.dataArray
```

It seems that the second way could save some code, but I heard that you shouldn't store data in views because it violates the MVC principle. Could you please give me some advice? Many thanks!

Comment: I would say they both look the same, just one has more wrapping paper. In both your are storing a reference to the data. In both cases you end up getting an array to use. You only need the wrapping if the structure of the data gets more complicated or has different options. I tend now to create a database class which I can ask for an instance of via a class method which moves all data management to a single location. e.g. [MyDatabase instanceWithId:<insert some id for the db you want>]. I then give the view controllers the id of the database to use.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel Thanks for your advice and I will think about that. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, I wouldn't subclass any UIView unless it's absolutely necessary. Both TableViews and Collections provide protocols to control their behavior correctly.

If I were you, in order to keep the ViewController clean and short, I would create a custom NSObject implementing both UITableViewDelegate and DataSource protocols. This class would be in charge of providing the style of cells and sections (that is shared in those 2 table views) and also the data source. Of course, this object must have a property referencing its TableView.

The ViewController would only be in charge of triggering data retrieval whenever is needed. That data should be passed to that custom NSObject, which would be in charge of updating the table view.

BTW, this object could even be added through InterfaceBuilder.

It's a bit old, I know, but you could check :[Lighter VC](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/lighter-view-controllers.html) It's just a step forward towards MVVM.

Comment: I have read that before... Thanks a lot for your suggestion! I'll definitely try that.